# How can i loop through values in mysql and use them as i go

Tags: php, mysql

ok so i have a database with emails, i want to loop through emails and send each one an email, i have a select statement that loops through emails but i dont know how to put the emails into my mail function

```
<?php
include_once("db.php");

$query = "SELECT email  FROM mailer";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   echo "<tr><td>" .$row['email']."</td><td>";

   $to = ".$row['email'].";
   $subject = "This is subject";
   $message = "This is simple text message.";
   $header = "From:abc@somedomain.com \r\n";
   $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
   if( $retval == true )  
   {
      echo "Message sent successfully...";
   }
   else
   {
      echo "Message could not be sent...";
   }

}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Just do: `$to = $row['email'];` ?!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it correct way.

Just some modifications.

Change:

```
$to = ".$row['email'].";
```

To:

```
$to = $row['email'];
```

You are making thing complex unnecessarily with use of `.` and `"`.

PS: Do not user *mysql_* functions, they are deprecated.

User *mysqli_* OR *PDO* instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send mail only then i don't know why you are trying to echo table. your code should be

```
<?php
include_once("db.php");



$query = "SELECT email  FROM mailer";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $subject = "This is subject";
   $message = "This is simple text message.";
   $header = "From:abc@somedomain.com \r\n";
   $retval = mail ($row['email'],$subject,$message,$header);
   if( $retval == true )  
   {
      echo "Message sent successfully...";
   }
   else
   {
      echo "Message could not be sent...";
   }
}
mysql_close();
?>
```